# Composer installation: global vs local

Tags: laravel, composer-php

I have a new server, where multiple clients will host their webapps at. From Wordpress, to laravel, to simple html shizzle.

As you may know, Laravel requires Composer to be installed. This can be done locally, but also globaly. I am wondering (if there are any) about the pros and cons.

Of course, you can run the global installation from anywhere. But can this be a issue for other development projects on the server, or are there security for the global installation?

Comment: You can install composer globally. As long as each client is set up with their own permissions running that global composer binary won't enable one client to affect something on another client's domain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The disadvantage of using a globally installed composer is this

- you're likely using different versions along the development pipeline
- you may end up with different results

Just as an example, in a project, we had `composer.phar` checked in and updated regularly, but we ran into problems when the version we used was already updated to be able to use the `^` operator, however, a different binary was used during deployment, unaware of that operator, and the deployment failed.

The safest bet is to use the same version of `composer.phar` along the development pipeline. Alternatively, as mentioned before, keeping the globally installed `composer` regularly updated.

Since we usually use `Makefile`s in our projects, here's an example of what it looks like:

```
.PHONY: composer cs it test

it: cs test

composer:
    composer self-update
    composer validate
    composer install

cs: composer
    vendor/bin/php-cs-fixer fix --diff --verbose

test:
    vendor/bin/phpunit --configuration=test/Unit/phpunit.xml
    vendor/bin/phpunit --configuration=test/Integration/phpunit.xml
```

Answer (score 2):

I would always suggest install globally, it will be easier for you to manage, and you could easily keep it up to date.

In the other projects they will not need to clutter their project with

```
composer.phar file
```